# Magento2: Add a custom image and link below account navigation in account dashboard

Tags: magento2, customer-account, navigation

below the account navigation is there an easy way for a newbie to add an image pointing to a page in the magento2?  This account navigation appears on the side of my account dashboard. 
thanks!

[image]

Comment: Here, you have to do so many things to show a profile image. I suggest you to check this extension:  https://marketplace.magento.com/sy-avatar.html

Comment: add code of inserting image in account information

Answer (score 1):

For the add image and there link in the below myaccount navigation dashboard.

**Follow below steps.**

> File path:
>   magento/app/design/frontend/Namespace/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new-sidebar-image-block" template="Magento_Customer::imageblock.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/design/frontend/Namespace/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/imageblock.phtml

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl()?>customer/account/" target="_self"><img src="<?php echo $block->getUrl("pub/media/myaccount/")?>image.png"/></a>
```

**Put your image to below path:**

```
pub/media/myaccount/image.png
```

Now run the command `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Check in myaccount image will appear.

Hope it help.

Comment: thanks.  I'm curios about the path, `magento/app/design/frontend/Namespace/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml`.  I'm currently using template monster from a vendor so would this still work or should I find my templates customer_account.xml instead?

Comment: It's works. Check and let me know if any issue.

Comment: I will check this evening thanks for your help!

Comment: so I tried this but its not working.  Currently I have two subfolders below /app/design/frontend they are Magento and templatemonster.  I tried two ways, first I made a seperate folder called test and put `./test/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml` but that did not work so I tried putting it under the subfolder magento but did not work as well.  Any other place I should try?

Comment: You have to need place the customer_account.xml in your theme below path.

app/design/frontend/templatemonster/yourtheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

Comment: Ok hmm I tried this.  I also went ahead and do a flush as well as magento setup:upgrade; but its still not showing up.  Do I need to register/initiate the custom template somewhere perhaps.